# How can i Redirect my sub-domain by new Domain?

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect-url, domain, subdomain

I have a website called **xyz.com** and added additional store called **abc.xyz.com**.

Now I have purchased new domain **123.com**.

How can I redirect my subdomain as a new domain, like if customer enter **123.com** it will be redirected to **abc.xyz.com**, and URL should be like **123.com** not changing to **abc.xyz.com** in the **URL bar**?

Comment: Solved my self, just add add-on-domain, path is your store root folder, simple.

Answer (score 0):

You Have to add below code into the `.htaccsess` file for that.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^123.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://abc.xyz.com/$1 [P]
```

Comment: Let me clarify this, now my .htaccess look like -> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)https://xyz-dot-com/abc/
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:abc_en],   Here how can i change?

Comment: better view : https://justpaste.it/6147s

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code in `.htaccess` file in Magento root after `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` tag.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abc.xyz.com/[R=301]
```

Comment: Where i can give my 123.com domain?

Comment: yes you can add your domain

Comment: output : https://snag.gy/0qfkXu.jpg my .htacces code : http://collabedit.com/j3m47 (if asking name enter : zus)